# Логика работы с хранимой процедурой через JDBC

Tags: jdbc, stored-procedures

У меня есть такой код, который выполняет два запроса:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            for (String script : scripts) {
                if (!script.trim().isEmpty() && !script.equals(scripts.get(scripts.size() - 1))) {
                    stmt.addBatch(script);
                }
            }
            stmt.executeBatch();
            try (CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(scripts.get(scripts.size() - 1))) {
                ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next()) {
                    res = (Long) rs.getObject(1);
                }
            }
```

`scripts` это лист строк:

```
[0] => call R.Component_update(@node_118594,1,20592,null,53,'',118601,0);
[1] => select @node_118594;
```

Первый параметр процедуры это `INOUT` параметр. В процедуре происходит `INSERT` записи и в переменную `@node_118594` присваивается `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Проблема в следующем. После запуска приложения перед вызовом `R.Component_update` в переменной `@node_118594` находится значение `NULL`, и в итоге логика отрабатывает корректно. Но если выполнить этот же запрос из программы (не перезапуская ее) повторно, перед вызовом `RE.Component_update` в переменной `@node_118594` уже лежит предыдущие значение, а мне это не нужно, нужно чтобы каждый раз там был `NULL`.

По какой причине так происходит, почему после выполнения куска данного кода, данная переменная не обнулилась?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам по хорошему надо вызывать хранимку так:

```
   String script="call RE.TariffComponent_update(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
   CallableStatement cs=conn.prepareCall(script);
   cs.registerOutParameter(1, Type.String); //регистрируем 1 аргумент как возвращаемый
   String s=null; //сюда "вернется" наше значение
   cs.setString(1, s);  //связываем выходное значение с переменной и задаем значение как null
   //ну и т.д. проходимся по остальным параметрам
```

Надеюсь идея понятна

Comment: не совсем понятно, `String s=null;` мы же здесь присваиваем жетско `null`. Каким образом сюда попадет возвращаемое значение из хранимки?

Comment: Присваивая `s=null` мы на вход подает `null`, а декларируя `cs.registerOutParameter(1, Type.String)` - мы говорим, что значение из первого параметра возвращаемое.

Comment: У вас похоже пробелы в том как работает `CallableStatement` - почитайте документацию и скачайте примеры

Comment: я вас понял. Проблема в том, что мне приходит строка вызова хранимки уже с заполненными параметрами: `call RE.TariffComponent_update(@node_118594,1,20592,null,53,'',118601,0);`. Из-за этого я не могу получается зарегистрировать первый параметр. На данной строке `callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.BIGINT);` падает с ошибкой: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

Comment: Конечно будет падать - он ищет в параметрах знак `?` и туда вставляет свой параметр, вам надо подавать на вход: `call RE.TariffComponent_update(?,1,20592,null,53,'',11‌​8601,0);`

Comment: дело в том, что я не могу изменить приходящую строку с вызовом. Я просто не могу понять, почему между вызовами этих методов, `select @node_118594;` возвращает предедущие значение этой переменной, почему данная переменная не умирает между вызовами хранимки? Если вынести `Connection conn` из блока `try`, все срабатывает, переменная не запоминается между вызовами.